# luhns algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, math, cs50, luhn

I've looked around the internet and I've seen a lot of other luhns algorithms for the same class I'm taking but it's hard to gauge what the difference in their code is vs mine. right now I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    long input;
    do
    {
        input = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (input < 0);

    long secondToLast, last;
    int i;
    long length = 0;
    long sum1 = 0;
    long sum2 = 0;
    long firstNum, secondNum, totalSum;

    //Finds the length of the input
    while (input > 0)
    {
        input/=10;
        length++;
    }
    printf("%li\n", length);
    //For loop goes through every 2 digits in
    //input and takes out the ones we want.
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i += 2)
    {
        secondToLast = input / (long)pow(10, i+1);
        secondToLast = secondToLast % 10;
        last = input / (long)pow(10, i);
        last = last % 10;
        printf("Second to last: %li\n", secondToLast);
        printf("Last: %li\n", last);

        //This is to separate the digits into individual digits.
        if (secondToLast * 2 > 10)
        {
            firstNum = secondToLast * 2 / 10;
            secondNum = secondToLast * 2 % 10;
            sum1 = sum1 + firstNum + secondNum - (secondToLast * 2);
        }
        //Add the digits we get
        sum1 = sum1 + secondToLast *  2;
        sum2 = sum2 + last;
        printf("Sum1: %li\n", sum1);
        printf("Sum2: %li\n", sum2);
    }

    totalSum = sum1 + sum2;
    printf("Total Sum: %li\n", totalSum);
    //Final step of checksum to see if the last digit is 0 or not.
    if (totalSum % 10 == 0)
    {
        printf("Valid \n");
    }
        else
    {
        printf("Invalid \n";)
    }
```

my code seems to be incorrect as when i print out the sums to check what the code is doing, they are all 0 and never get changed. it worked before, but i don't recall ever changing the code to the point where it doesn't work. if anyone could please take a look and show me where i could be messing up would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't get the input as a number. Get it as a string so you can easily loop over the digit.

Comment: The loop that gets the length of `input` modifies `input`. You need to save the original value so you can process it with the rest of the code.

Comment: @barmar how would using a string make it easier/better to loop over?

Comment: You don't need to use a loop to count the digits. Also, credit card numbers can have leading zeroes, but numbers don't.

Comment: Credit card numbers commonly have 16 digits. That's ok if a `long` is 64 bits, but it doesn't work if a `long` is 32 bits. The C specification only guarantees that a `long` is at least 32 bits.  So you *are* better off with a string, since the string can be whatever length you choose.

Comment: but i'll be adding and subtracting the input nad other math operations on it. doesn't that mean i'll have to cast it to int or long anyways?

Comment: All the math is done on the individual digits. The conversion from a character code to an `int` is simply `int digit = string[i] - '0';`

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your algorithm, where you are trying to get the length of your number:

```
    //Finds the length of the input (and destroy input forever)
    while (input > 0)
    {
        input/=10;
        length++;
    }
    /* here you can ensure that input is always zero,
     * because of the two clauses stated below, continue
     * reading... */
```

You get out of the loop only when your `input` variable reaches 0, so after that all your algorithm deals with a `0` in `input`, and no way of knowing the digits anymore.  You have destroyed your input.

Before that, you did

```
while (input < 0);
```

so in case your input was negative, your program would block in a loop (with an empty body) in which nothing is done to `input` so you will never get out of there.